# Marklogic - Invalid entity reference issue

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I am using [**xdmp:document-load**](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:document-load) function in MarkLogic 8 version

When inserting an XML document into MarkLogic Database I got the following Error message:

> **Invalid entity reference "lsquo"**

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 4):

This is not an encoding issue, but has more to do with document types and DTDs. Plain XML only supports out of the box `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&amp;`, `&apos;`, and `&quot;`. Entities like `&lsquo;` come from the HTML entity set, and also often used in other (proprietary) DTDs. You either need to provide a local DTD subset in the prolog of the file, resolve those entities to Unicode upfront, or rely on the 'repair' feature of MarkLogic.

The `repair` option is probably the quickest way out, but it might be worth thinking a bit harder where these entities came from, and what you want to do with them.

Here is the documentation of `xdmp:document-load`, that should describe the `repair` option:

http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:document-load

HTH!

Comment: Since it's working, could you mark this answer as accepted? That gives credit to grtjn and makes it clear that this question has been resolved.